# AJAX doesn't send data, I can't use POST Result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

EDIT :

I would like to have a button value in another page.
I've think to use Ajax, but I dn"t know if it's the best way..

Here is my **Form:**

```
<form id="form_prj">
    <button class="btn_prj" type="button" name="var_prj" value=60>Afficher</button>
</form>
```

Here is my **Ajax:  projet.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_prj', function() {
            var sendData = {
                lid: this.value
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../pit_app/carte.php',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    lid: sendData,

                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    window.location = './carte.php';
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error Occured");
                }
            });
        });
```

Here **get_data.php**

```
<?php
include('fonctions.php');
$connect = connect();
if(isset($_POST["lid"])) {
    $btn_value = $_POST['lid'];
}else{
    echo ("Error");
}
$sql1 = "SELECT row_to_json(fc)FROM (
    SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features 
    FROM (
    SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_transform(ST_SetSRID(geom, 2154), 
    4326))::json As geometry, row_to_json(n) As properties 
    FROM chambre As n,projet WHERE ST_Contains(zone_etude,geom) and id_projet=" . $btn_value . ") As f)  As fc;";

$result = pg_query($connect, $sql1);
$rs = pg_fetch_array($result);
$legeojson = $rs[0];
?>
```

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtMpm.png)

EDIT2:

Ok, I added my query to the isset and now I have another problem.
In my third file, carte.php where I included get_data.php

I have `var geojson = </ br>` 
But I need

```
var geojson = <?php echo $legeojson;?>;
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: legeojson in
>   E:\wamp\www\stage_axians\pit_app\carte.php on line 108

Comment: did you get any error ?

Comment: i can see that first you have to replace data: {lid: sendData} with {'lid': sendData}

Comment: What debugging have you already done?

Comment: Yes, like Unefined index lid  in carte.php

Comment: Ok, I'm trying, 
I've tried, method GET, POST, REQUEST.. Async: false etc..

Comment: The above code would _not_ give you "Unefined index lid".  Are you perhaps trying to access it in one of the included files that you're not showing?

Comment: I simplified my code, but the idea remains the same, there is probably a problem with my included files. I can modify the post and show you

Comment: What you need to do is include the full and exact error message in your question.  Not something "like" it.  You should also make sure you are showing the code referenced by the error message (which will include a file and line number).  As I said, the message you mentioned above simply does not match up with the code.  So either you're giving us the wrong error message or the wrong code.

Comment: Sorry, i'm going to modify the post

Comment: Please include the text of the essential error message *in your question*. What value would `$btn_value` have if *not* `isset($_POST["lid"])`?

Comment: If you require the posted value to run your query (which it seems that you do), then you should include your query _within_ your `if(isset($_POST["lid"]))` check.  Otherwise you are running the query code regardless of whether the posted data is present or not.  Also, I highly recommend that you use prepared statements with bound parameters instead of injecting PHP variables into your query.  Finally, the way that you're doing it now, `$_POST['lid']` is not going to contain a simple value like you think it is. See the answer below for the fix to that.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some small clean up of your code. Your click action was a bit wrong, to get the button instance by its name you can usee `$('[name="var_prj"]')` which mean that `$(this)` will return exactly this button in the body of the `click` event

Next, to get the value from the button `value` attribute you can use `$(this).attr('value')` if you want to get value from `input` tags you can use simple `$(this).val()`.

And the last part is a `data` parameter of your `AJAX` call. If you already have an object with key and value, just put to the `data` param of the `$.ajax`

```html
<form id="form_prj">
    <button type="button" name="var_prj" value=60>Afficher</button>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[name="var_prj"]').click(function () {
            var sendData = {
                lid: $(this).attr('value'),
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../pit_app/carte.php',
                cache: false,
                data: sendData,
                success: function (data) {
                    window.location = './carte.php';
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error Occured');
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is the `$_POST` array of your `carte.php` after sending AJAX request.

```
Array
(
    [lid] => 60
)
```

Hope my answer would help to you

Comment: Thank for your help, but now the click doesn't show anything

Comment: @VincentReynier To get value of `lid`, just use `$_POST['lid']` in your `get_data.php` file.

Comment: @VincentReynier and It seems we are sending all data to the wrong handler. I think we should send everything to the `get_data .php`, then please replace `url: '../pit_app/carte.php'` to `url: 'path/to/get_data.php'` (make sure that your path to the file is correct).